# writing to output all updated IDs

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I please need some advice.

I have an update statement that updates one ID to another ID
How can I write to the SQL output log so that it shows the old ID and what it updated to.

```
update employees e
set e.employee_ID = 'EMP006'
where e.employee_ID in (select e.employeeID from employees, employee_type et
                     where employee_type = 'CASUAL'
                     and e.employee_id = et.employee_id);
dbms_output.put_line('expected inserted records:44,actual:'||SQL%ROWCOUNT);
```

IE. employee_ID 1 was updated to EMP006
    employee_ID 2 was updated to EMP007

Comment: On a side note: You shouldn't use comma-separated joins anymore. Oracle made them redundant in 2001 with Oracle 9i and they were already nine years late at that, as explicit joins (`from a inner join b on ...`) were introduced in standard SQL in 1992. Moreover that join isn't even necessary in your query. It only produces a large intermediate result by duplicating all IDs multifold in the subquery (cartesian product / cross join). At last: employee_ID 2 was not updated to EMP007 of course. The update statement sets employee_IDs to EMP006.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RETURNING` clause. You can return an aggregated string with `LISTAGG`.

```
declare
  v_ids varchar2(4000); 
begin
  update employees
  set employee_id = 'EMP006'
  where employee_id in (select employee_id from employee_type where employee_type = 'CASUAL')
  returning listagg(employee_id, ',') within group (order by employee_id) employee_id
  into v_ids;

  dbms_output.put_line('Updated IDs: ' || v_ids || ' to EMP006');

end;
```

For more complicated things I would rather select the rows in a loop and update and collect data inside that loop.